# Can't start TOR as a daemon on FreeBSD

Tags: networking, permissions, freebsd, daemon, tor

I'm trying to understand why TOR does not start as a service on my FreeBSD 13.2. This is the error message that I see during the boot :

```
[notice] Tor 0.4.8.9 running on FreeBSD with Libevent 2.1.12-
stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1t-freebsd, Zlib 1.2.13, Liblzma 5.4.1, Libzstd
1.5.5 and BSD 1302001 as libc.

[notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be
safe at [URL]https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous
/[/URL] 

[notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc". 

[notice] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.1.2:9100'
for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use 
your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 

[notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 

[notice] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050

[notice] Opening Socks listener on 192.168.1.2:9100 

[notice] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 
192.168.1.2:9100 

[warn] /var/db/tor is not owned by this user (_tor, 256) but by
root (0). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user? 

[notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener connection
(ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050 

[notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener connection 
(ready) on 192.168.1.2:9100

[warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't create private 
data directory "/var/db/tor" 

[err] Reading config failed--see warnings above. 

/etc/rc: WARNING: failed to start tor
```

and this is the TOR config file :

```
SOCKSPort 9050
SOCKSPort 192.168.1.2:9100 
RunAsDaemon 1
DataDirectory /var/db/tor
Nickname me
ContactInfo me <me@world.com>
ExitRelay 0
ExitNodes {ch} StrictNodes 0
```

Comment: What if you launch it manually as root ?

Comment: it works : https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/MwQTTVDqqj/ ; but I want that it starts during the boot,not manually,at the end of it.

Comment: Therefore the problem is there : */var/db/tor is not owned by this user (_tor, 256) but by
root (0). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user? * . In the times I was using FreeBSD services should always be launched as root. apparently _tor is the owner, therefore : 1/ Check is this is normal 2/ if yes then change owner of /var/db/tor to _tor.

Comment: ... and then start it using the proper service start-up script: `# service tor start`